# Setting a variable after mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".squares").on('mouseover', function(){
 $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
```

getRandomColor() is a function which returns a random color function when a square in a grid is mouseovered.

I want to be able to go over once and the color changes, but if i go over a second time the color will stay the same. Right now the color just repeatedly changes after every mouseover. I know its probably going to require an if statement. I just don't know how to set the statement equal to a back-ground color.

Comment: Have a look at [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: @M.Doye, I don't think so.

Comment: .one seemed to work perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(".squares").one('mouseover', function() {
 $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a 'data-' attribute, so you know if it has already been changed?

Comment: I agree with your suggestion but it looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I thought I was adding a comment. Day #1 on the iOS app!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind()` event. This would unbind the `mouseover` event once its already invoked.

```
$(".squares").on('mouseover', function(){
 $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
    $(this).unbind('mouseover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j6um1sq2/17/

Comment: .unbind stops it from working on other squares in the grid.

Comment: oops. didn't realize that. fixed it now by targeting 'this' element